# JW Player advertising - javascript code

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, ads

There is any way i can add using JW Player javascript API ads on the video that are provided by the advertising network in javascript format :

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="true" charset="utf-8" 
src="http://ro.search.etargetnet.com/generic/advert.php?
g=ref:xxx,area:655x90,tabl:4,divid:,design_name:custom,border_color:ffffff,
h_url_color:0067d6,freespace:0,logo_type:4,logo:1,title_underline:0,
url_underline:0,h_title_underline:1,h_url_underline:1,nourl:,fsi:11,font:verdana" >
</script>
```

TX

Comment: We only support VAST tags